# WordPress Page hierarchy ( parent is singular of custom post types slug ) is returning not found

Tags: custom-post-types, page-template, custom-post-type-archives

I have a custom post type called **CASINOS** with slugs is *casinos*
wich has _archive set to false

and I have a page called Casino with slug casino ( singular)

The problem is when creating a child with a parent Casino page, the page returns not found.
But if I change the casino page slug to something other than casinos or casino, it will work fine.
so what I have is

www.example.com/casino ( parent )
www.example.com/casinos/custom-post-type-slug ( casino post type)

what I want to achieve is

www.example.com/casino/new

here I have the casino post type has_archieve set to false

Comment: What are the full arguments you're using to register the post type?

Comment: 'label' =>Casinos
        'labels' => $casino_labels,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'menu_position' => 13,
        'show_in_admin_bar' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'has_archive' => false,
        'capability_type' => 'page',
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-admin-home',
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'casinos', 'with_front' => false),        
    );

Comment: did you try to go to settings > permalinks > use plain once for trial and check the `post name` and save to test again? Make sure you haven't got anything called `casion` for rewrite including taxonomy and so on and make sure there is no other plugins interfere your test.

Comment: i Did check that , and there were some wired taxonomy with slug casino , thank you so much